# Javascript Circular Dependency

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please can someone explain what the issue is with my code. What I am trying to achieve is to create an array from fruits array (see code block), where array=[name: "Banana", name: "Orange", name: "Apple", name: "Mango"]

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
myFunction(fruits)

function myFunction() {
    var array=[];
    var item = {};
    fruits.forEach(function(entry, index){
    item.name=entry

    array.push(item);

});

console.log(array)

}
```

However when I print array to the console, this is what I get:
[[object Object] {
  name: "Mango"
}, [circular object Object], [circular object Object], [circular object Object]]

The first object gets populated correctly, but I don't understand why it is saying there is a circular dependancy for the others. Can anyone please help me to explain what the issue is and how I should resolve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[name: "Banana", name: "Orange", name: "Apple", name: "Mango"]` isn't a valid JS object, you can homever have:

`[{name: "Banana"}, {name: "Orange"}, {name: "Apple}, {name: "Mango"}]` which is an array of objects, to do in a loop:

```
function myFunction() {
  var array=[];

  fruits.forEach(function(entry) {
    array.push({ name: entry });
  });

  console.log(array)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the same object multiple times.

```
function myFunction() {
  var array=[];

  fruits.forEach(function(entry, index) {
    var item = {};
    item.name=entry

    array.push(item);
  });

  console.log(array)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!